# Is it statistically correct and safe to calculate Kappa 2 test means of combinations of 2 against the value of a Fleiss' Kappa?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

For my problem I have a group of `p participants` and `s subjects`. I was suggested to calculate the Kappa Cohen Test on combinations of two for `p` and `s`, then calculate the `mean` and compare against the uniquely calculated value of Fleiss` kappa for the same set.

My question is, whetheror not it is correct/safe to calculate a mean over the Cohen's kappa test?

More specifically, I am using the Kappa2 and Fleiss' kappa with the flag set to FALSE from the [irr R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irr/index.html). Setting the flag to false means that a variant algorithm of Kappa Fleiss is used so that it can be reduced to Kappa Cohen when the population has p=2 s=2.